# OneDrive API - Getting File Not Found most of the time when attempting to get file contents

Tags: onedrive

We are getting lots of file not found errors. When calling the API, we have a slim chance of getting the file. We are having this issue in production and it is affecting clients. This started earlier yesterday. We've been calling this api for months without issue. This is the API we're using.

https://TENANT-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drives/DRIVE_ID/items/FILE_ID/content

Using Postman, the response is below. This document is shared properly and has been for months. Nothing changed on our side.

Sorry, something went wrong
Sorry, you cannot access this document. Please contact the person who shared it with you.
Technical Details

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
Correlation ID: fb6bbf9d-d0d6-2000-cdd6-ef99686d513f

Date and Time: 12/9/2016 9:13:02 AM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this doesn't explain the how or why the API broke, as of this writing, OneDrive has not acknowledged nor fixed the original issue, our solution was to use the value of the @contentDownloadUrl from the meta of the file and make a call to that url without the authorization header.

The docs currently state:

"Pre-authenticated download URLs are only valid for a short period of time (a few minutes) and do not require an Authorization header to download."

This should not say "do not require", but "must not include", as it would be more clear. I have made a pull request to their docs.

Comment: Thanks for the investigation here @Burnsy and @JEBoothjr, I'm seeing a few other reports of similar issues recently. I'll drill in to the behavior when the `Authorization` header is also provided.

Comment: I had the same issue and opened a github issue - https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/485

Comment: Is that really what we're supposed to do, make an issue on the docs if there is an issue with the API itself? If so, I'll make note of it.

Comment: While there's certainly no harm in not providing the `Authorization` header for when using the download URLs it should not be necessary. What you were observing was a regression in the service that has since been resolved. We apologize for the inconvenience, and have taken steps to minimize the chances of similar issues in the future.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem using the C#/.NET SDK with ItemNotFound error and 'Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException'. This started after MS did an update to OneDrive on 12/7.  We opened a support ticket with O365/OneDrive team.  They said they are not aware of any issues from rollout and said we needed to contact API support.  The weird thing is it works sometimes, maybe 2 out of 100 tries.  Listing files and uploading still work but downloads fail.

Here's what we have tried so far:

- Latest sample project from GitHub, same error
- Check settings in SharePoint for new settings that may affect this,none found
- Re-register the App in Azure AD
- Increased app permissions in Azure AD

The line of code that fails is:

var stream = await this.oneDriveClient.Drive.Items[item.Id].Content.Request().GetAsync();

Comment: We're using the REST API and we are experiencing similar success rates. We also tried modified versions of the call and still no success. How does one get in contact with API support or O365/OneDrive team? I dug all over trying to find the appropriate channel.

Comment: The doc, https://dev.onedrive.com/terms-of-use.htm provides information about terms of use and details our support boundaries.

 It also provides your support options at the bottom of the page.

 Those options are
 Support
 User Voice and
 Stack Overflow

 There you can get assistance with programming issues or note issues with the API, again I apologize about any inconvenience this issue may have caused you. 

 Best regards
 Steve

 Microsoft Office 365 Support

 

Thank you,
 Steven Clark
 Office 365 Support

Comment: I opened the support ticket using the Admin interface in O365, it goes to email: office365support@microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with authentication.  This code seems to fix it:

```
            var adalAuthProvider = new AdalAuthenticationProvider(
                    this.AadClientId,
                    this.AadReturnUrl);

            this.oneDriveClient = new OneDriveClient(this.AadTargetUrl + "/_api/v2.0", adalAuthProvider, new HttpProvider(new HttpClientHandler { AllowAutoRedirect = true }, true));
            authTask = adalAuthProvider.AuthenticateUserAsync(this.AadTargetUrl);

            try
            {
                await authTask;
            }
```

Comment: I'm realizing the same thing. If I use the @content.downloadUrl value with a Auth header, I'm able to recreate the issue. If I use that value and remove the auth header, I'm able to get "content", but our parser is failing on it, so I think its returning the file itself and not the contents of the file?

Comment: There was a minor issue on my end. @contentdownloadUrl is working. But I have to remove my auth header on that call.